# Как отправить сообщение от группы пользователю при помощи библиотеки vknet

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet

Как мне реализовать отправку сообщения пользователю VK, который написал сообществу, я получаю сообщение от пользователя, беру его ID, но я не знаю как отправить сообщение ему в ответ, посмотрел в доках VkAPI, написано что нужно юзать message.send, если это так,то объясните пожалуйста, как именно нужно им пользоваться???

Comment: Ну для начала надо залогиниться в API. С этим вы уже справились? Что уже умеете? Какую библиотеку для доступа в API испрользуете?

Comment: Если правильно вас понимаю, использую библиотеку VkNet,, уже залогинился, сообщения от пользователя приходят в консоль приложения, изучать API начал буквально вчера, потому мало что умею

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из документации к Vk.net:

`Message` - Текст личного cообщения (является обязательным, если не задан параметр attachment) строка

`UserId` - Идентификатор пользователя, которому отправляется сообщение. целое число

`RandomId` - Уникальный (в привязке к API_ID и ID отправителя) идентификатор, предназначенный для предотвращения повторной отправки одинакового сообщения. Сохраняется вместе с сообщением и доступен в истории сообщений. Заданный RandomId используется для проверки уникальности за всю историю сообщений, поэтому используйте большой диапазон(до int32). целое число, доступен начиная с версии 5.45

Пример отправки сообщения Павлу Дурову

```cs
api.Messages.Send(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams
{
    RandomId = 123, // рандомный id, 
    UserId = 1,
    Message = "message"
});
```

https://vknet.github.io/vk/messages/send/

Comment: Это частично отвечает на вопрос автора. Автор также хотел узнать, как отправить сообщение так, чтобы автором сообщения была группа

Comment: Отправляется сообщение от имени группы,всё отлично,но почему-то реагирует только один раз

Comment: @ЯрикЛотоцкий в каком плане реагирует один раз?

Comment: @DeMmAge Пользователь вконтакте пишет сообщение, после чего бот отвечает ему, но когда пользователь пишет ещё раз, бот уже не реагирует

Comment: @ЯрикЛотоцкий random id меняется?

Comment: @DeMmAge Да,я не особо понимаю зачем он нужен,но он является обязательным аргументом

Comment: @ЯрикЛотоцкий является. Ты его, надеюсь, рандомно генерируешь?

Comment: @DeMmAge Конечно

Answer (score -4):

В документации есть примеры на php

```
define('VK_API_VERSION', '5.67'); //Используемая версия API
define('VK_API_ENDPOINT', "https://api.vk.com/method/");

//Функция для вызова произвольного метода API
function _vkApi_call($method, $params = array()) {
  $params['access_token'] = VK_API_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  $params['v'] = VK_API_VERSION;
  $url = VK_API_ENDPOINT.$method.'?'.http_build_query($params);
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $json = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  $response = json_decode($json, true);
  return $response['response'];
}

//Функция для вызова messages.send
function vkApi_messagesSend($peer_id, $message, $attachments = array()) {
  return _vkApi_call('messages.send', array(
    'peer_id' => $peer_id,
    'message' => $message,
    'attachment' => implode(',', $attachments)
  ));
}

vkApi_messagesSend(494075, 'Hello world!');
```

На последней строке как раз и реализована оправка сообщения в ответ. Главное, не забудьте присвоить ваш серверный секретный ключ и версию api`шки.

Comment: Это похоже на с# ? Или хотя бы на код который можно вставить в С# код что бы он работал при этом?